# Google App Engine Query matches case

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Say I query the datastore with:

```
query = self.request.get('q')
query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM UserProfile WHERE username = :query", query=query)
```

The UserProfile table has an entry:

```
userid    username
1         Ron
```

So when I query with `username="Ron"` it return the object but not with the query `username="ron"`. Is it possible to query the datastore keeping the query case-insensitive?

Also, does Google Datastore has query similar to Django's as below?

```
c = Col.objects.filter(name__istartswith = request.GET['term'])[:3]
```

Comment: store it in lower case, convert it to lowercase when you search. Or store the lower case version also, then search for that after converting the search term also.

Comment: THe easiest way to store the duplicate normalized case form of the property is use a ComputedProperty https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#computed